# Unicode "end of story"

Tags: unicode

I'm looking for a good character that means "end-of-story" in unicode. I remember seeing one once that looked like a fractal and was really cool. Does anyone know where I can find this character? More importantly, where can I go to find a unicode character with a special meaning when I don't know it's names? Google wasn't very helpful.

Comment: Unicode is not programming related?!!!

Comment: @AgnelKurian It's mechanics are. The history and semantics of every one of the thousands of characters in the UCS is a matter of languistics, not programming. As fascinating as that is, knowing that ๛ and ៙ mean "end of book/story" isn't programming.

Comment: @Jon, I agree with you in a broad sense. However, if we go on like this, then the whole of stack overflow will end up being fragmented into a million pieces. For example, is the equation of a straight line programming related? What about the orientation of a polygon? I'm sure those who were on SO during its early days will remember how much more useful the site was without these restrictions. Just my $0.02.

Comment: @AgnelKurian I'm inclined to support a liberal view on such matters, but in this case, how is it even vaugely related to programming?

Comment: @Jon, Unicode is a common topic that many programmers have to deal with. Just have a look at the number of questions tagged Unicode on SO.

Comment: What does this question have to do with Unicode apart from the fact that the characters - like every other character - are in Unicode? It's no more relevant than the history of the carolignian miniscule, or the influence of Franciscan monks on the half-unical script when printed, or the Qabalic values associatied with Hebrew letters. All of which are indeed very interesting, but not programming-related.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Edit: I found something that looks kinda like a fractal, and also happens to be called "end-of-story." It's a Thai character.

[Is this](http://www.decodeunicode.org/en/u+0e5b/properties) what you were looking for?

http://www.decodeunicode.org/en/u+0e5b/data/k//XS/khomut31910809.jpg

> *End of story The Khomut sign is a terminal punctuation character which is placed in old books at the end of a verse in a poem, the end of a chapter or at the end of a story.*
> Compare to U+17DA Khmer Sign Koomuut

Btw: I found this with a Google Image Search on **`"end of story" unicode`**--It was the 4th result. That's probably the best way to search for any kind of symbol. Though without the name of the character it would probably have been impossible to find, since **`unicode fractal`** didn't return anything useful.

Comment: That website that you linked to http://www.decodeunicode.org/en/ is excellent!

Comment: here they are as text: `U+17DA`: ៚ and `U+E5B`: ๛

Answer (score 5):

Go and have a look at the unicode.org code charts. You can browse through them and find a character that you like by what they look like. http://www.unicode.org/charts/

Alternatively, browse through the names of the characters using the data file that has the official character name. Do a search using your browser or editor search function. http://www.unicode.org/Public/5.1.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt

When you find a character that you want to see what it looks like, just do a search for the character code. e.g. character 0087 (the first field in the UnicodeData.txt file) is searched as [U+0087](http://www.google.com/search?q=u%2B0087). FileFormat.info usually has all of the characters. For example, [END OF SELECTED AREA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0087/index.htm).

Comment: Um, I'm sorry to sound pathetic, but I'm pretty new here and the upvote / answer buttons seem to be missing. They disappeared. They aren't near your answer any more. Which is a shame, because I'd like to give you an upvote. I must missing something obvious, but I can't find those buttons. Do you know what's going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Windows?  Use the Character Map (Start | Accessories | System Tools).  I personally like the Greek Omega (U+03A9) or the Ohm sign which is an Omega (U+2126).